# Работа с удаленным MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Собственно, купил хост для сайта. Там через cPanel создал новую SQL бд.

Хочу для начала хотя бы для начала подключиться к ней.

```
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = myServerAddress; 
    Initial Catalog = myDataBase; User Id = myUsername; Password = myPassword;");

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
  command.Connection = conn;
  command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  command.CommandText = "Select myColumn from myTable";
  using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (dr.Read())
    {
      results.Add(dr["myColumn"].ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Этот код я нашел на просторах того же stackoverflow. Подделал под себя -> выдача ошибки при коннекте к базе.

[image: Exception]

Как я получал адрес: (Указал свой внешний IP как узел)
[image: скриншот]

Помогите! Знаний с SQL 0, а то и -1.

Comment: У меня строка соединения к mysql выглядит так: `"server=server IP; database=mydatabase; port=3306; user=myuser;"`

Comment: @tym32167,А можешь исходник дать?

Comment: дать исходник чего?

Comment: @tym32167, А. Всё. Понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. почему переменные указаны через пробел? "Data Source = myServerAddress; 
   Initial Catalog = myDataBase; User Id = myUsername;" Или это норма?
2. чтобы получить доступ к удаленной машине следует учесть несколько параметров - завести пользователя для удаленного подключения. Как это сделать - указано [тут](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Adding_users.html). Также, следует настроить сам сервер mysql таким образом, чтобы он слушал 3306 порт не на 127.0.0.1 (localhost), а на внешнем интерфейсе - смотрите конфиг my.cnf (последние версии Mysql этим грешат).

   3. Проверьте доступность драйвера для СУБД под C#

Comment: Святой бубен! Ужас

Comment: Если требуется помощь, могу подключиться и посмотреть.